# One column to be used more than once in pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have 12 columns of value, each corresponding to a month in a year. Now I need quarterly YTD summary showing in a Pivot Table, e.g. Q1 will be `Jan + Feb + Mar`, Q2 will be `Jan + ... + Jun`. One way to accomplish this is by adding four columns, Q1, Q2, Q3, and Q4, in Pivot Table manually. Is there another way to accomplish this without generating Q1 to Q4 at the beginning?

Thanks

Comment: If you have the actual dates in the source table as well then its easy: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Group-or-ungroup-data-in-a-PivotTable-report-c9d1ddd0-6580-47d1-82bc-c84a5a340725

Comment: @pnuts Hi, adding Calculated items is the method that I already mentioned. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: I think I understand what you are asking, but I want to clarify to be sure.

You want to be able to create a pivot table an treat Columns A,B, and C as a single column for a quarterly summary of the sum of all. Is this correct?

Comment: @viper941 Yes. A, B, C as Group 1, A, B, C, D, E, F as Group 2, and etc. The reason that I don't like Calculated items/fields is that, it is static. When it comes a new year's data, I need to add those Calculated items again.

Answer (score 0):

Since I completely missunderstood the question here is my edit:

On your pivot table sheet place the "Q" number in one cell (so "Q1" -> 1)

In your datasheet create a new column with the following formula:

```
 =SUM(INDIRECT("A:"&CHAR(64+Sheet2!N2*3)))
```

My formula is made for pivot table on Sheet2 and Q-value in N1. Change to suit

Remember that each time you change the Q-value you need to refresh the pivot table.
This can be made with a macro

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Worksheets("Sheet2").PivotTables("Pivottable").PivotCache.Refresh  ' change sheet name and pivot table name
End Sub
```

It reacts on each time there is a change on the sheet.

[image]

Comment: @pnuts that was confusing. Usually when you talk about Q1, Q2 etc. it's three months at the time. I'll see if I can edit it tomorrow to suit him